# не работают Bootstrap RadioButton

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap

Я в веб программировании почти новичок. Имею следующий код, где не могу разобраться в чем причина почему не переключаются RadioButtons. Если убрать классы `col-*-*` частично некоторые кнопки становятся работоспособными.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Start", "Login"))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2">Я:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="iam" checked="checked">Девушка</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="iam">Парень</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Start" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете классы col* но при этом не оборачиваете из в класс row, из-за чего верстку перекашивает, и не получается выбрать радиобаттоны

```html
<form action="/Login/Start" method="post">                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2">Я:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="iam" value="2">Девушка</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="iam" value="1">Парень</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Start" class="btn btn-success">
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял: col должен всегда быть обернут в row? А row в container?